# Word crashes on removing a Shape with VBA from a header

Tags: vba, ms-word

<sup>(disclaimer: i'm **not** a VBA programmer by occupation)</sup>

Attached to buttons in the Ribbon I have code to toggle the company logo in a Word Document. 
One button for the logo type A, a second button for logo type B and a third for no logo (logo is preprintend on paper)

First I remove the logo with `removeLogo` and then i add it the requested logo with `setLogoAt`.

The first button click is fine (e.g. for Logo Type A), a logo is added to the header of the document. When i click an other button (e.g for Logo Type B) Word crashes (probably on removing the current logo)

What is wrong with my code (or less probably: with Word?)

```
Sub setLogoAt(left As Integer, path As String)
    Dim logoShape As Shape
    Dim anchorLocation As Range

    Dim headerShapes As Shapes
    Set logoShape = ActiveDocument.  'linebreks for readability
        .Sections(1)
        .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
        .Shapes
        .AddPicture(FileName:=path, LinkToFile:=False,
                    SaveWithDocument:=True, left:=0, 
                    Top:=0, Width:=100, Height:=80)

    logoShape.name = "CompanyLogo"
    logoShape.RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
    logoShape.RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
    logoShape.Top = CentimetersToPoints(0.1)
    logoShape.left = CentimetersToPoints(left)

End Sub

Sub removeLogo()
    Dim headerShapes As Shapes
    Set headerShapes = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes
    Dim shapeToDelete As Shape

    If (headerShapes.Count > 0) Then
        If Not IsNull(headerShapes("CompanyLogo")) Then
            Set shapeToDelete = headerShapes("CompanyLogo")
        End If
    End If
    If Not (shapeToDelete Is Nothing) Then
      shapeToDelete.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

**edit**

I steped trough my code. All is fine until I reach the line `shapteToDelete.Delete` in `removeLogo`. Here Word crashes hard, even while debugging. I'm using **Word 2007** (and that is a requirement)

**edit2**
I cleared all macros, all normals.dot, all autoloading templates, then created a new document with the two routines above and this test method:

```
Sub test()
    setLogoAt 5, "C:\path\to\logo.jpg"
    removeLogo
    setLogoAt 6, "C:\path\to\logo.jpg"
End Sub
```

When I run `test` it crashes in `removeLogo` at `shapeToDelete.Delete`.

**Edit 3** 
I 'solved' the problem by first making the headers/footers view the active view in Word, then deleting the Shape and then returning to normal view. Very strange. It works but as a programmer I'm not happy.

Comment: These both run without error for me, regardless of the order and number of times called.  They happily add and remove logos.  You've clearly got other code that calls these.  Perhaps the error is there, or in the button code itself.  You need to debug, e.g., step through with F8, to determine the exact spot it crashes.

Comment: You've got an interesting one here.  I ran your test code, and it worked perfectly the first two times, then it crashed Word the 3rd time, and then it worked perfectly the next 14 times.  There's something going on, but it looks like it is non-repeatable on some machines.  I wish you luck, sorry I can't contribute.

Comment: Thanks for all your effort! Seems that there is something really wrong with my Word 2007 installation. I'll try to find an other instance to test on.

Answer (score 1):

Another potential solution is to try and select the shape first and then delete the selection:

shapeToDelete.Select
Selection.Delete

You would probably want to switch off screen updating if this works, else you'll get flickering as Word moves around the document.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this problem before and normally with an automation error: "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients". I haven't yet found a solution.

However a good workaround is to hide the shape rather than delete it.

So:

shapeToDelete.Visible = False

Answer (score -1):

This works:
 I only have 2 boxes to hide so this isn't generic

```
Private Sub btnPrint_Click()
    Dim hdrShapes As Shapes
    Dim S As Shape
    Dim aTohide(2) As String
    Dim iNdx, i As Integer
    iNdx = 0

     ' Hide buttons and print
    Set hdrShapes = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes
    ' GET BUTTON NAMES (ACTUALLY TEXT BOXES
    For Each S In hdrShapes
        If S.Type = msoTextBox Then
            aTohide(iNdx) = S.Name
            iNdx = iNdx + 1
        End If
    Next
    ' now hide , use the arrays as the  for each statement crashes
    For i = 0 To 1
        hdrShapes(aTohide(i)).Visible = msoFalse
    Next
    ' print it
    With ActiveDocument
        .PrintOut
    End With
    ' and unhide the buttons
    For i = 0 To 1
        hdrShapes(aTohide(i)).Visible = msoTrue
    Next

    Set hdrShapes = Nothing
End Sub
```